# Reload parent window when new window refresh or reload

Tags: jquery

im not sure if can explain this well, im new to jquery, It goes something like this, I have a parent window and in the parent window there's a link button and when the link button was clicked a modal popup will appear and in the modal popup there's a button, when i click the button a new window will open and the popup window will close, my exact requirement is that, when the new window refresh or reload thats the time the parent window will also reload or refresh. They said this is possible in jquery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try `if(window.parent) { window.parent.location.reload(); }`

Or even better, do not use popups but inline "popups", i.e. divs - like those: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: im currently using telerik popup as per requirement for the project, by the way the new window im talking about is not within my application, its a different website, so when I click the button it will hit the url of that webpage, so if that webpage was refresh or reload, that's the time my page will reload also, i have to do the code within my application only, and i cannot do any code on the other webpage or website.

Comment: Then it's impossible. You cannot even access each other's data via JS for security reasons.

Comment: someone told me to try to use this $(selector, context)
var newwindow= window.open(www.otherwebsite.com)
$(selector, newwindow.document), but he did not know what to put as selector and i have no idea on how i will come up to that requirements

Comment: so far this is my idea or pseudocode, $(URL to other page).bind('OnReload', function() {
window.opener.location.href=   window.opener.location.href 
});

Comment: There is no `onreload` event.

Comment: so meaning, there's no other work around based on my pseudocode?